# Why doesn't the spring DefaultSerializer#serialize method close the ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: spring, serialization

The **serialize** method in org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer doesn't close the ObjectOutputStream, why?

```
public class DefaultSerializer implements Serializer<Object> {

/**
 * Writes the source object to an output stream using Java Serialization.
 * The source object must implement {@link Serializable}.
 */
public void serialize(Object object, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    if (!(object instanceof Serializable)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(getClass().getSimpleName() + " requires a Serializable payload " +
                "but received an object of type [" + object.getClass().getName() + "]");
    }
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
    objectOutputStream.flush();
}

}
```